# The correct statements are

Tags: maxima-minima

For every pair of continuous functions  $f,  g$  $: \left[0, 1\right] \rightarrow R $, such that $max(f(x) : x \in \left[0, 1\right]) $$= $ $max( g(x) : x \in \left[0, 1\right] )$  , the correct statement(s) is(are)

(1)$(f(c))^2  + 3f(c) = (g(c))^2  + 3g(c)$ for some $ c  \in  [0, 1] $

(2)$(f(c))^2  + f(c) = (g(c))^2  + 3g(c)$ for some $ c  \in  [0, 1] $

(3)$(f(c))^2  + 3f(c) = (g(c))^2  + g(c)$ for some $ c  \in  [0, 1] $

(4)$(f(c))^2 = (g(c))^2 $ for some $ c  \in  [0, 1] $

My work

In this one possibility  is that they have same maxima, assume it to be $c$ and this will satisfy option $1$ and $4$

Is there any other possibility than this ?

Comment: What tells you their respective maxima are attained at the same point $c$ (which appears to be what you assume in your last paragraph)?

Comment: It is the possibility.

Comment: What do you mean? You are asked to state which statements are *always* true given the assumptions on $f,g$ not those that "could maybe be true for *some* particular choice of $f,g$."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr:** 1. and 4. are true (but not for the reason you gave), 2. and 3. are false (there are counterexamples). Namely, you are asked to give the statements that are true *for all $f,g$ satisfying the assumptions*, not those that are true *for some $f,g$ satisfying the assumptions.*

- Your last paragraph assumes that $f$ and $g$ attain their common maximum on the *same* point $c\in[0,1]$. This needs not be the case (and there are very simple counterexamples). However, we can show that there exists some $c\in[0,1]$ for which $f(c)=g(c)$ (but this may not be the maximum value).

  In more detail: let $h = f - g\colon[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$. It is a continuous function; let $x_f$ (resp. $x_g$) be the point at which $f$ (resp. $g$) achieves its maximum. If $x_f=x_g$, we are done; otherwise, since $h(x_f) \geq 0$ and $h(x_g) \leq 0$, the intermediate value theorem (IVT) ensures that there exists $c\in[x_f,x_g]$ such that $h(c)=0$.

  Now, we have that $c\in[0,1]$ for which $f(c)=g(c)$, which indeed proves that 1. and 4. are true.
- Let us focus on 2. and 3. now. Since the statements and the assumptions on $f,g$ are symmetric in $f,g$, it is enough to prove or disprove only one the the two statements. Let us disprove 2. by choosing simple functions $f,g$ possible:
  $f(x)=g(x)=x+1$. It is not hard to see that there is no $x\in[0,1]$ such that $(x+1)^2+(x+1)=(x+1)^2+3(x+1)$ (since the only solution to this equation is $-1$).

Comment: lol, I even picked the same counterexample

Comment: That's a nice coincidence :) Another possible counterexample would be $f(x)=g(x)=e^x$ (which *never* cancels, not even outside $[0,1]$).

Answer (score 0):

As @Clement C. pointed in the comments, you're reasoning is wrong. You must show which of these statements are true for *every* such $f, g$

Let $f, g$ be such functions, $M = max \{f(x) : x \in [0, 1]\}$ and $a : f(a) = M, b : g(b) = M$. Then, if $a = b$ we're done. Otherwise, we can assume $a < b$ without loss of generality and consider $h = f - g$, having

$$h(a) = M - g(a) \geq M - M = 0$$
$$h(b) = f(b) - M \leq M - M = 0$$

Then, by Bolzano there must exist $c \in [a, b] : h(c) = 0 \iff f(c) = g(c)$, proving that both 1 and 4 are true.

For 2 and 3, consider $f(x) = g(x) = x + 1$. If such a $c$ existed we'd have $(x+1)^2+3(x+1)=(x+1)^2+(x+1) \iff 3x + 3 = x + 1 \iff x = -1$, which is impossible in $[0, 1]$. The other case is analogous.